# Get input from a keyboard that is activated by a UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I am able to activate a keyboard when users touch a label in either a `UITableViewCell` or `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:[cell bounds]];
[tf setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
[cell.lblTest addSubview:tf];
[cell.lblTest setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

[cell.lblTest setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %d", indexPath.row]];
```

Here is the outcome:

[image]

My questions:

1) How I can obtain input from the keyboard, and

2) Dismiss the keyboard when user changes cell selection.

Comment: make sure to use - tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectCellAtIndex:(NSInteger)index method of UITableView delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dismiss the keyboard when user click out of your textfield :

add an iboutlet for your textfield

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textInput;
```

add this to your viewController

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if ([self.textInput isFirstResponder] && [touch view] != self.textInput) {
        [self.textInput resignFirstResponder];
    }
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: `IBOutlet` is for **I** nterface **B** uilder **outlets**; he adds the text field in code.

Comment: @LeoNatan, so, just a normal property : `@property (strong, nonatomic)  UITextField *textInput;`

Answer (score 2):

Your can either become the text field's delegate or listen to `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` notifications for the specific text field to hear of changes. To dismiss the keyboard, call `resignFirstResponder` on the text field.

But this is a bad design. You add more and more text fields to your view hierarchy. You should at least remove them when dismissing the keyboard.
Also, what are you trying to achieve? Displaying a keyboard without feedback to the user about key input (such as a **visible** text field or text view), is not a very good practice.

Comment: I agree it is probably a bad UI design. It is more an exercise of technical feasibility.